# Python Memory Leakage (Causing Memory Error): Memory is increasing incrementally even after calling garbage collector and deleting large variable

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

```
import numpy as np
import pdfplumber
import os
import psutil
import gc

file = 'path.pdf'
pdf = pdfplumber.open(file)
pages = pdf.pages
print('Total pages in pdf = '+str(len(pages)))

startPage = 3
chunkSize = 50

while(startPage < 250):
    print('Iteration')
    print('Memory at the start : ',end='')
    print((psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss)/(1024 * 1024),' MBs')

    endPage = startPage + chunkSize
    extract_pages = pages[startPage: endPage] 
    print(str(extract_pages[0])," to ",str(extract_pages[-1]))
    
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for page in extract_pages:
        df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(np.array(page.extract_table()))], axis = 0)
        del page
        
#   df.to_csv()
    del df, extract_pages
    gc.collect()
    print('Memory at the end : ',end='')
    print((psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss)/(1024 * 1024),' MBs',end='\n\n')
    
    startPage = startPage + chunkSize 

print('finished')
```

OUTPUT:
Total pages in pdf = 17225
Iteration
Memory at the start : 818.91015625  MBs
Page:4  to  Page:53
Memory at the end : 819.61328125  MBs

Iteration
Memory at the start : 819.61328125  MBs
Page:54  to  Page:103
Memory at the end : 963.703125  MBs

Iteration
Memory at the start : 963.703125  MBs
Page:104  to  Page:153
Memory at the end : 1324.65625  MBs

Iteration
Memory at the start : 1324.65625  MBs
Page:154  to  Page:203
Memory at the end : 1686.01171875  MBs

Iteration
Memory at the start : 1686.01171875  MBs
Page:204  to  Page:253
Memory at the end : 2047.60546875  MBs

finished

(Extracting text from pdf)

Comment: Deleting those variables won't help, because they are immediately recreated in the next loop iteration.

Comment: Decoded size of pdf file in memory is ~134.9352 MB's but the memory occupation increased by calling extract_table(). 
Note: The memory leakage issue has been resolved by replacing del page with page.flush_cache() as answered by @edg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [this issue](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber/issues/193).

I ran your code as is, with a 170 pages, 3.1MBs PDF. Ended up with :

```
Memory at the end : 1321.90625  MBs

Finished duration 55.18302297592163 secs.
```

With a context manager to open the PDF and with using `page.flush_cache()`, I get :

```
Memory at the end : 90.8125  MBs

Finished duration 68.00025987625122 secs.
```

Yes it is slower, as said in the github issue, but at least the memory leak is much much smaller.

Working snippet (I removed the chunk for this example) :

```
import numpy as np
import pdfplumber
import os
import psutil
import gc
import pandas as pd
from time import time

start = time()

with pdfplumber.open("file.pdf") as pdf:
    pages_len = len(pdf.pages)

print(f'Total pages in pdf = {pages_len}')

with pdfplumber.open("file.pdf") as pdf:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    print('Memory at the start : ',end='')
    for index, page in enumerate(pdf.pages):
        if not index % 10:
            print(f'=== Page index {index} === ')

        print((psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss)/(1024 * 1024),' MBs')
        
        table = page.extract_table()
        df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(np.array(table))], axis = 0)
        page.flush_cache()

    gc.collect()
    print('Memory at the end : ',end='')
    print((psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss)/(1024 * 1024),' MBs',end='\n\n')


print(f'Finished duration {time() - start} secs.')
```